# Linking against a shared object but undefined reference occurs?

Tags: linker, g++, shared-libraries, nm

I am in a bit of a pickle. I do not seem to be able to figure out where the problem is: I have a simple test file (test.cpp):

```
#include <RMF.h>
#include <RMF/FileHandle.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    RMF::FileHandle fh;
        fh = RMF::create_rmf_file("/home/kkarius/junk/test_rmfs/run_109_frame_6963.rmf3");  
    std::cout << "yep" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And I use the following two commands to compile and link my test file.

```
g++ -Wall -I./include -c test.cpp
g++ -v -g -L./lib64/ -o test test.o -lRMF
```

The olders and files I link are:

```
bash-4.2$ ls lib64/
cmake              libimp_display.so    libimp_isd.so.0     libimp_modeller.so       libimp_pepdock.so.0    libimp_scratch.so
libimp_algebra.so      libimp_display.so.0  libimp_kernel.so        libimp_modeller.so.0     libimp_pmi.so      libimp_scratch.so.0
libimp_algebra.so.0    libimp_domino.so     libimp_kernel.so.0      libimp_mpi.so        libimp_pmi.so.0        libimp_statistics.so
libimp_atom.so         libimp_domino.so.0   libimp_kinematics.so    libimp_mpi.so.0      libimp_rmf.so      libimp_statistics.so.0
libimp_atom.so.0       libimp_em.so     libimp_kinematics.so.0  libimp_multi_state.so    libimp_rmf.so.0        libimp_symmetry.so
libimp_benchmark.so    libimp_em.so.0       libimp_kmeans.so        libimp_multi_state.so.0  libimp_rotamer.so      libimp_symmetry.so.0
libimp_benchmark.so.0  libimp_example.so    libimp_kmeans.so.0      libimp_npc.so        libimp_rotamer.so.0    libimp_test.so
libimp_container.so    libimp_example.so.0  libimp_misc.so      libimp_npc.so.0      libimp_saxs.so     libimp_test.so.0
libimp_container.so.0  libimp_foxs.so       libimp_misc.so.0        libimp_parallel.so       libimp_saxs.so.0       libRMF.so
libimp_core.so         libimp_foxs.so.0     libimp_mmcif.so     libimp_parallel.so.0     libimp_score_functor.so    python2.7
libimp_core.so.0       libimp_isd.so        libimp_mmcif.so.0       libimp_pepdock.so        libimp_score_functor.so.0
```

and

```
bash-4.2$ ls include/
IMP  IMP.h  RMF  RMF.h
```

While the compile command works out nicely, the linking doesn't:

```
bash-4.2$ g++ -v -g -L./lib64/ -o test test.o -lRMF
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ./configure --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (GCC) 
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/:/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/:/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../lib64/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-g' '-L./lib64/' '-o' 'test' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/collect2 -plugin /usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccKz3qw4.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o test /lib/../lib64/crt1.o /lib/../lib64/crti.o /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/crtbegin.o -L./lib64/ -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0 -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../.. test.o -lRMF -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/crtend.o /lib/../lib64/crtn.o
test.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `RMF::create_rmf_file(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
bash-4.2$ g++ -g -o test test.o lib64/libRMF.so 
test.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `RMF::create_rmf_file(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit statusexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccKz3qw4.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o test /lib/../lib64/crt1.o /lib/../lib64/crti.o /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/crtbegin.o -L./lib64/ -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0 -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../.. test.o -lRMF -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/crtend.o /lib/../lib64/crtn.o
test.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `RMF::create_rmf_file(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
bash-4.2$ g++ -g -o test test.o lib64/libRMF.so 
test.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `RMF::create_rmf_file(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I had a look into the file libRMF.so where I found the method I need:

```
bash-4.2$ nm lib64/libRMF.so | grep create_rmf_file
00000000009fd6e2 T _ZN3RMF15create_rmf_fileESs
```

Now I am in the situation that I think I did everything right, yet obviously I didn't! Can someone point out my mistake?

All the best 
Kai

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OCCI linkage error with gcc 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309029/occi-linkage-error-with-gcc-5)

Comment: You, Sir, were absolutely correct. If you want to elevate it to an answer, we can close the topic!